# What is the difference between exit and quit in jsch's ChannelSftp?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I'm currently developing a program with jsch, and I am looking at the ChannelSftp class.
I just want to know the difference between the quit and exit method.

In the help string of the [Sftp example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java) it says `"exit - Quit sftp"` and `"quit - Quit sftp"`.

So, what's the difference between the two and how do you use these properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are same. Internally they call just    `disconnect();`:

```
public void quit(){ disconnect();}

public void exit(){ disconnect();}
```

The inofficial JSch documentation makes this clear: [`exit`](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#exit%28%29), [`quit`](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#quit%28%29).

Comment: Client Side they are identical.
Some sftp server implementations prefer to explicitily    receive a *QUIT* command, which help to close resources server side.
So calling quit() with jsch does not implement the desired behavior